# Default linker setting in Makefile for linking C++ object files

Tags: makefile

Consider this `Makefile`

```
% cat Makefile
main: main.o add.o
```

which uses `cc` instead of `g++` to link the object files

```
% make
g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x   -c -o add.o add.cpp
cc   main.o add.o   -o main
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x40): undefined reference to `std::cout'
...
```

How do I tell (GNU) Make to use `g++` (which links the C++ libraries) instead of `cc`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

(GNU) Make has built-in rules, which is nice, because it is enough to give dependencies without rules:

```
main: main.o add.o
    # no rule, therefore use built-in rule
```

However the build-in rule in this case uses `$(CC)` for linking object files.

```
% make -p -f/dev/null
...
LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
...
LINK.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
...
%: %.o
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

To let Make chose the correct linker, it is sufficient to set `LINK.o` to `LINK.cc`. A minimal `Makefile` can therefore look like

```
% cat Makefile
LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x

main: main.o add.o
```