# Confused how my Makefile is remaking object files

Tags: c++, makefile

My make file is failing to find my include directory when it tries to remake object files. For example, when I call `make tests` I get the output:

```
g++    -c -o sdl_class.o sdl_class.cpp
sdl_class.cpp:9:23: fatal error: sdl_class.h: No such file or directory
#include <sdl_class.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [sdl_class.o] Error 1
```

My Makefile is this:

```
#Originally from: http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/
#But will be heavily modified
IDIR =../include
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-w -I$(IDIR)

#ODIR=obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lSDL2

_DEPS = sdl_class.h SDL_image.h 
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

OBJ = sdl_class.o tests.o 
#OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

tests: sdl_class.o tests.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

all: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ core $(IDIR)/*~
```

My understanding is that when I call `make tests`, that it should attempt to remake the sdl_class.o file. This should then call the `%.o` rule, which should try to make the object file by calling something like:

```
g++ -c -o sdl_class.o sdl_class.cpp -w -I../include -lSDL2
```

However, this is not the case as it looks like it is calling `$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)`, as you can see from above.

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding about how make builds its rules? Seems likely, this is my first Makefile. Perhaps I am confused on how compilation works in general, as I'm somewhat new to that as well.

Comment: Let the compiler determine the `_DEPS ` using e.g. the GCC `-MM` option, and include the result to your makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the problem is that one or more of the files `../include/sdl_class.h` or `../include/SDL_image.h` does not exist.  Because of that, make is deciding that your pattern rule does not match (because not all the prerequisites can be found or made) and it defaults to the built-in rule to create object files from `.cpp` files.

The built-in rules use the make variables `CXX` for the C++ compiler and `CXXFLAGS` for the C++ flags: the `CC` and `CFLAGS` variables are used for the C compiler.  That's why your settings for `CFLAGS` are being ignored.

If you run `make -d sdl_class.o` you'll see which file make is looking for and why it decides to not use your pattern rule.

If you rewrite your rules like this it will work better:

```
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

sdl_class.o tests.o: $(DEPS)
```

because make will now complain that the relevant files can't be found or created.

There are other issues, of course.  You shouldn't be passing `$(LIBS)` to your compile command; that belongs only in your link line.  And, you should probably stick to the standard variables `CXX` for the C++ compiler, `CPPFLAGS` for preprocessor flags like `-I` and `-D`, and `CXXFLAGS` for C++ compiler flags.  Also, linker library flags like `-L../lib` go in `LDFLAGS` and linker libraries like `-lSDL2` go in `LDLIBS`.

Comment: Your answer was extremely helpful! I have modified my Makefile to try to include all of the suggestions you made. I feel like I understand what you are saying with them well enough as well, so thanks for that! I had no idea that these variable had special names, I had assumed they were arbitrarily named but had conventions. If it's not too much trouble, could you check out [my current version](https://gist.github.com/okiyama/132ce4ceed885b151d4c) and let me know if I got it right? If not, where can I fix it up a bit more?

Comment: The `-W*` flags are not preprocessor flags so they belong in `CXXFLAGS` not `CPPFLAGS`.  These variable names _are_ conventions... because make as a number of built-in rules and these are the variables that the built-in rules use.  In fact you can delete your pattern rule for `%.o : %.cpp`, if you want, because GNU make already knows how to do that using a built-in rule.  However, these variable names are not special to make in any way beyond that.

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense, thanks again! I was going off of [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) to decide what to put in `CXXFLAGS` and what to put in `CPPFLAGS`. That link has everything I was using, so I thought it was all preprocessor. Is there any further reading I could do to better learn the difference between compiler flags and preprocessor flags? It's cool that GNU Make has so many smart rules baked into it.

Answer (score 0):

CC/CCFLAGS are for C compilation. You should use CXX and CXXFLAGS for C++. They are used in built-in rules and in the LINK.cc macro, making the Makefile much simpler, and thus less error prone.

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall ...
prog :  foo.o bar.o
      $(LINK.cc) -o $@ $^
```

see [Default linker setting in Makefile for linking C++ object files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375394/default-linker-setting-in-makefile-for-linking-c-object-files)